# Converting from HSV (HSB in Java) to RGB without using java.awt.Color (disallowed on Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, colors, rgb, hsv

I figured I should post this question, even if I have already found a solution, as a Java implementation was not readily available when I searched for it.

Using HSV instead of RGB allows the generation of colors with the same saturation and brightness (something I wanted).

Google App Engine does not allow use of java.awt.Color, so doing the following to convert between HSV and RGB is not an option:

```
Color c = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, value);
String rgb = Integer.toHexString(c.getRGB());
```

Edit: I moved my answer as described in the comment by Nick Johnson.

Ex animo, - Alexander.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but you should post the answer _as_ an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll do that tomorrow and edit the question. (At the moment I got an error: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead")

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know anything about color math, but I can offer this alternative structure for the code, which tickles my aesthetic sense because it made it obvious to me how each of the 6 cases is just a different permutation of value, t and p.  (Also I have an irrational fear of long if-else chains.)

```
public static String hsvToRgb(float hue, float saturation, float value) {

    int h = (int)(hue * 6);
    float f = hue * 6 - h;
    float p = value * (1 - saturation);
    float q = value * (1 - f * saturation);
    float t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation);

    switch (h) {
      case 0: return rgbToString(value, t, p);
      case 1: return rgbToString(q, value, p);
      case 2: return rgbToString(p, value, t);
      case 3: return rgbToString(p, q, value);
      case 4: return rgbToString(t, p, value);
      case 5: return rgbToString(value, p, q);
      default: throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong when converting from HSV to RGB. Input was " + hue + ", " + saturation + ", " + value);
    }
}

public static String rgbToString(float r, float g, float b) {
    String rs = Integer.toHexString((int)(r * 256));
    String gs = Integer.toHexString((int)(g * 256));
    String bs = Integer.toHexString((int)(b * 256));
    return rs + gs + bs;
}
```

Comment: That is indeed a lot prettier, at the mere cost of another method invocation.

Comment: I'm optimistic that either the compiler or the JIT would inline the extra method if it were a major performance gain.

Comment: Sorry to drag up a 2 year old thread, but I wondered if someone would confirm something for me - should `rgbToString` multiply by `255`, not `256`?  Because otherwise, when `r` is `1.0`, `rs` would be `100` in hex, which is wrong.

Comment: Yes, although if you simply multiply by 255, then results like 0.9999 will get truncated to 254, which is not correct either. A correct algorithm would implement the rounding present in java.awt.Color.HSBtoRGB()

Comment: If your hue value is exactly 1, then h could easily be 6, throwing an unnecessary exception.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/blob/550b542f5f1b9981029bef60576f63b1a93feb5c/schemacrawler-api/src/main/java/sf/util/Color.java for a complete realization of the code above, which takes into account round results, and having the hue be any float.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the HSBtoRGB implementation provided by Oracle, copying its source code into your project. java.awt.Color is open-source. The algorithms provided by Peter Recore and Yngling are not robust and will return illegal RGB values like "256,256,0" for certain inputs. Oracle's implementation is robust, use it instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use [ColorUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html) which provides

```
HSLToColor(float\[\] hsl)
```

And

```
[RGBToHSL(int r, int g, int b, float\[\] hsl)]
```

Methods which are very easy to convert to each other!

For example:

```
float[] hsl = new float[]{1.5, 2.0, 1.5};
int color = ColorUtils.HSLToColor(hsl);
```

Now get the color

```
float[] hslStub = new float[3];
float[] hslFromColor = ColorUtils.colorToHSL(color, hslStub);
```

Now get the hsl

Here is the [sourcecode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.java).

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found here: http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically/

Martin Ankerl provides a good post on the subject, and provides Ruby script. For those too busy (or lazy) to implement it in Java, here's the one I did (I am sure it can be written more effectively, please feel free to comment):

```
public static String hsvToRgb(float hue, float saturation, float value) {
    float r, g, b;

    int h = (int)(hue * 6);
    float f = hue * 6 - h;
    float p = value * (1 - saturation);
    float q = value * (1 - f * saturation);
    float t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation);

    if (h == 0) {
        r = value;
        g = t;
        b = p;
    } else if (h == 1) {
        r = q;
        g = value;
        b = p;
    } else if (h == 2) {
        r = p;
        g = value;
        b = t;
    } else if (h == 3) {
        r = p;
        g = q;
        b = value;
    } else if (h == 4) {
        r = t;
        g = p;
        b = value;
    } else if (h <= 6) {
        r = value;
        g = p;
        b = q;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong when converting from HSV to RGB. Input was " + hue + ", " + saturation + ", " + value);
    }

    String rs = Integer.toHexString((int)(r * 255));
    String gs = Integer.toHexString((int)(g * 255));
    String bs = Integer.toHexString((int)(b * 255));
    return rs + gs + bs;
}
```

Comment: The last else condition should probably say `| else if (h <= 6) {`. And the conversion should be `(r * 255)` etc not `* 256` since the color range is 0 to 255.

Comment: @ehartwell: Edited based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

My code for converting:

```
     /**
     * @param H
     *            0-360
     * @param S
     *            0-100
     * @param V
     *            0-100
     * @return color in hex string
     */
    public static String hsvToRgb(float H, float S, float V) {

        float R, G, B;

        H /= 360f;
        S /= 100f;
        V /= 100f;

        if (S == 0)
        {
            R = V * 255;
            G = V * 255;
            B = V * 255;
        } else {
            float var_h = H * 6;
            if (var_h == 6)
                var_h = 0; // H must be < 1
            int var_i = (int) Math.floor((double) var_h); // Or ... var_i =
                                                            // floor( var_h )
            float var_1 = V * (1 - S);
            float var_2 = V * (1 - S * (var_h - var_i));
            float var_3 = V * (1 - S * (1 - (var_h - var_i)));

            float var_r;
            float var_g;
            float var_b;
            if (var_i == 0) {
                var_r = V;
                var_g = var_3;
                var_b = var_1;
            } else if (var_i == 1) {
                var_r = var_2;
                var_g = V;
                var_b = var_1;
            } else if (var_i == 2) {
                var_r = var_1;
                var_g = V;
                var_b = var_3;
            } else if (var_i == 3) {
                var_r = var_1;
                var_g = var_2;
                var_b = V;
            } else if (var_i == 4) {
                var_r = var_3;
                var_g = var_1;
                var_b = V;
            } else {
                var_r = V;
                var_g = var_1;
                var_b = var_2;
            }

            R = var_r * 255; // RGB results from 0 to 255
            G = var_g * 255;
            B = var_b * 255;
        }

        String rs = Integer.toHexString((int) (R));
        String gs = Integer.toHexString((int) (G));
        String bs = Integer.toHexString((int) (B));

        if (rs.length() == 1)
            rs = "0" + rs;
        if (gs.length() == 1)
            gs = "0" + gs;
        if (bs.length() == 1)
            bs = "0" + bs;
        return "#" + rs + gs + bs;
    }
```

Example of use on Android:

```
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((ColorOperations.hsvToRgb(100, 100, 57))));
```

Comment: hello are you still alive??

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Peter Recore do not use rounding.

Probably somewhat more correct way to use it is to copy the content from java.awt.Color and this is how it looked in Java 6:

```
 public static int HSBtoRGB(float hue, float saturation, float brightness) {
        int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
        if (saturation == 0) {
            r = g = b = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
        } else {
            float h = (hue - (float)Math.floor(hue)) * 6.0f;
            float f = h - (float)java.lang.Math.floor(h);
            float p = brightness * (1.0f - saturation);
            float q = brightness * (1.0f - saturation * f);
            float t = brightness * (1.0f - (saturation * (1.0f - f)));
            switch ((int) h) {
            case 0:
                r = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (t * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            case 1:
                r = (int) (q * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            case 2:
                r = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (t * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            case 3:
                r = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (q * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            case 4:
                r = (int) (t * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            case 5:
                r = (int) (brightness * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                g = (int) (p * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                b = (int) (q * 255.0f + 0.5f);
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | (b << 0);
    }
```

Rounding here seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using SWT you can use following code snippet:

```
RGB rgb = new RGB(r, g, b);
float[] hsbColor = rgb.getHSB();
rgb = new RGB(hsbColor[0], hsbColor[1], hsbColor[2]);
```

Comment: Confirmed. Although the `(int,int,int)` constructor accepts RGB, the `(float,float,float)` constructor accepts HSB.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but all the answers I've seen here multiply the hue with 6. This is wrong. I took a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and there it says that you have to **divide by 60**.

Here is one which I tested written in Kotlin

```kotlin
fun hsvToRgb(hsv: FloatArray): IntArray {
    val (hue, saturation, value) = hsv
    val h: Int = (hue / 60).toInt()
    val f = hue / 60 - h
    val p = value * (1 - saturation)
    val q = value * (1 - f * saturation)
    val t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation)

    val rgb = when (h) {
        0    -> floatArrayOf(value, t, p)
        1    -> floatArrayOf(q, value, p)
        2    -> floatArrayOf(p, value, t)
        3    -> floatArrayOf(p, q, value)
        4    -> floatArrayOf(t, p, value)
        5, 6 -> floatArrayOf(value, p, q)
        else -> throw Exception()
    }.map { it * 255 }
    val (r, g, b) = rgb
    return intArrayOf(r.toInt(), g.toInt(), b.toInt())
}
```

Here my Java implementation

```java
public static int[] hsvToRgb(float[] hsv) {
        final float hue = hsv[0];
        final float saturation = hsv[1];
        final float value = hsv[2];
        final int h = (int) hue / 60;
        final float f = hue / 60 - h;
        final float p = value * (1 - saturation);
        final float q = value * (1 - f * saturation);
        final float t = value * (1 - (1 - f) * saturation);

        float[] rgb = switch (h) {
            case 0 -> new float[]{value, t, p};
            case 1 -> new float[]{q, value, p};
            case 2 -> new float[]{p, value, t};
            case 3 -> new float[]{p, q, value};
            case 4 -> new float[]{t, p, value};
            case 5, 6 -> new float[]{value, p, q};
            default -> throw new IllegalStateException();
        };
        rgb[0] = rgb[0] * 255;
        rgb[1] = rgb[1] * 255;
        rgb[2] = rgb[2] * 255;
        return new int[]{(int) rgb[0], (int) rgb[1], (int) rgb[2]};
    }
```