# LibGDX - Using android libs

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have three projects

1. Game - Java Project
2. GameAndroid - Android
3. GameDesktop - Java Project

I want to access **android.graphics.Color**, but I'm in my Game project which is java, so i can't do that. When I try to access **Java.awt.Color** insted, i'll get **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** insted.

Is there a way to access any of these libraries ?

for example i would like to use this method:

```
Color.getHSBColor();
```

Comment: Could you include a snippet of the code where you are using this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally recommend using `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color` instead.

It has the advantage of being platform-agnostic - but do note the implementation differences between the analogues.

For example, compare Android's implementation (AWT's works in the same fashion) :

```
public static int argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
    return (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}
```

and the libgdx implementation:

```
public static int toIntBits (int r, int g, int b, int a) {
     return (a << 24) | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
}
```

As you can see, the ordering in the encoding is different. Here's the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.java)
 for reference.

If you're looking for stuff such as HSB->RGB conversion, this can be implemented "manually". See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896280/converting-from-hsv-hsb-in-java-to-rgb-without-using-java-awt-color-disallowe), for example - but remember to use the libgdx implementation to generate the actual int from the RGB components!

Comment: Is there equivalent to Color.getHSBColor() ? I could not find it, so I started using java.awt.

Comment: I don't see anything like this in the 0.9.3 source code. However, this is easily solved with a short piece of code, see my answer edit for examples.