# Writing Custom HSB Color Function - Android

Tags: java, android, colors

The HSB color space is perfect what I'm doing (as the hue value is calculate between 0-360, whilst the S & B  remain at a constant 100) within my Android app.

The Color class in the java.awt.Color has this function, however the Android.Color does not, therefore I'm looking for possibly a custom implementation, or a solution to this problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: How's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896280/converting-from-hsv-hsb-in-java-to-rgb-without-using-java-awt-color-disallowe) look?

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917978/321697) helpful. When I got the answer, I'd moved on from that project and never got a chance to try it, but from a posted comment it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figure a solution to this problem.

The color space HSV works similar to HSB purely from a value perspective.

You can define the Saturation and Luminosity as constants once you're happy e.g. 255 = 1f for each, then simply increasing the hue value will slowly work through the color range.