# How to convert HSL color to other like RGB, Hex?

Tags: android

I'm developing color converter app in which one enters Hue, Saturation and Lightness values in EditText. When convert button is clicked the HSL value is converted to RGB and Hex. Then these values are set to TextViews.
My question is how to convert HSL color value to other colors like HEX, RGB etc.

Here is my code:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundLin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hueEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="000"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/satEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="000"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ligEt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="000"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertBtn"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:text="Convert"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rgbTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hexTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mHueEt, mSaturationEt, mLightnessEt;
    TextView mRgbTv, mHexTv;
    View mPreviewView;
    Button mConvertBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHueEt = findViewById(R.id.hueEt);
        mSaturationEt = findViewById(R.id.satEt);
        mLightnessEt = findViewById(R.id.ligEt);
        mConvertBtn = findViewById(R.id.convertBtn);
        mRgbTv = findViewById(R.id.rgbTv);
        mHexTv = findViewById(R.id.hexTv);
        mPreviewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        mConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float hue = Float.parseFloat(mHueEt.getText().toString().trim());
                float saturation = Float.parseFloat(mSaturationEt.getText().toString().trim());
                float lightness = Float.parseFloat(mLightnessEt.getText().toString().trim());

                //HSL
                int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{hue, saturation, lightness});
                //RGB
                int red = Color.red(color);
                int green = Color.green(color);
                int blue = Color.blue(color);
                int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
                //Hex
                String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue);

                try {
                    mHexTv.setText("Hex: " + hex);
                    mRgbTv.setText("RGB: " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
                    mPreviewView.setBackgroundColor(color);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Converting from HSL to RGB color values is already covered in a lot of Stackoverflow posts, for instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896280/converting-from-hsv-hsb-in-java-to-rgb-without-using-java-awt-color-disallowe).

Comment: it is HSV I need to convert HSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source Link:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils

**import this class:**

```
import static android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils.HSLToColor;
```

Change your onClick code as below:

```
mConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float hue = Float.parseFloat(mHueEt.getText().toString().trim());
            float saturation = Float.parseFloat(mSaturationEt.getText().toString().trim());
            float lightness = Float.parseFloat(mLightnessEt.getText().toString().trim());

            //store H,S,L values in float array
            float[] color = {hue, saturation/100, lightness/100};
            //convert hsl values to int color
            int intColor = HSLToColor(color);
            //RGB
            int red = Color.red(intColor);
            int green = Color.green(intColor);
            int blue = Color.blue(intColor);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(intColor);
            //Hex
            String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue);

            try {
                mHexTv.setText("Hex: " + hex);
                mRgbTv.setText("RGB: " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
                mPreviewView.setBackgroundColor(intColor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below method

```
Color color = Color.HSVToColor( new float[]{ hue, saturation , lightness } ) );
```

and for convert color to rgb use

```
int red = Color.red(color );
int green = Color.green(color );
int blue = Color.blue(color );
int alpha = Color.alpha(color );
```

Comment: Icompatible types:
                required: android.graphics.Color
                fount: int

Comment: Change variable type from Color to int

Comment: thanks both. changing variable type from Color to int has fixed the issue

Comment: i test it not problem, please write input here

Comment: Input: hsl(205, 63, 52)
Output rgb(0, 149, 255) but according to w3schools.com it should be rgb(55, 145, 210)

Comment: @HasnainJutt correct i use hsv instead hsl, post editied

Comment: @YasharPanahi  Cannot resolve method 'HSLToColor(float[])'

Comment: Input: hsl(205, 63, 52) Output rgb(0, 149, 255) but according to w3schools.com it should be rgb(55, 145, 210)

Answer (score 0):

From one of the answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion). you use the below function to convert your HSL color to RGB color.

```
Note that all integer are declared as float (i.e 1f) and must be float, else you will optain grey colors.
HSL to RGB

 /**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param h       The hue
 * @param s       The saturation
 * @param l       The lightness
 * @return int array, the RGB representation
 */
public static int[] hslToRgb(float h, float s, float l){
    float r, g, b;

    if (s == 0f) {
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    } else {
        float q = l < 0.5f ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        float p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hueToRgb(p, q, h + 1f/3f);
        g = hueToRgb(p, q, h);
        b = hueToRgb(p, q, h - 1f/3f);
    }
    int[] rgb = {(int) (r * 255), (int) (g * 255), (int) (b * 255)};
    return rgb;
}

/** Helper method that converts hue to rgb */
public static float hueToRgb(float p, float q, float t) {
    if (t < 0f)
        t += 1f;
    if (t > 1f)
        t -= 1f;
    if (t < 1f/6f)
        return p + (q - p) * 6f * t;
    if (t < 1f/2f)
        return q;
    if (t < 2f/3f)
        return p + (q - p) * (2f/3f - t) * 6f;
    return p;
}
```

Change your onClick code as below

```
mConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float hue = Float.parseFloat(mHueEt.getText().toString().trim());
                float saturation = Float.parseFloat(mSaturationEt.getText().toString().trim());
                float lightness = Float.parseFloat(mLightnessEt.getText().toString().trim());

                //HSL
                int anscolor[] = hslToRgb(hue, saturation, lightness);
                //RGB
                int red = anscolor[0];
                int green = anscolor[1];
                int blue = anscolor[2];

                String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue);

            try {
                mHexTv.setText("Hex: " + hex);
                mRgbTv.setText("RGB: " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
                mPreviewView.setBackgroundColor(color);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }
        });
```

Comment: **Input:** hsl(205, 63, 52)  **Output:** RGB: 832575, 832575, 832575  Hex: #cb43fcb43fcb43f

Comment: hsl input should be in [0,1] range.

Comment: I'm new in android please use and edit my code in your answer

Comment: I've already tried in the same way you have updated your answer now

Comment: you said HSL input should be in [0,1] range, but HSL values can be Hue[0-360], Saturation[0-100], Lightness[0-100]

Comment: code is based on algorithm from wikipedia, check this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV